# I want to add space between the strings which dont have space between them

Tags: javascript, regex, cypress

I am using cypress and I am handling a web table.and I have extracted the values out of it  and converted it into an array but what has happend  is the spacing is inconsistent. Now I want to have values with consistent spaces eg:
Actual Output :

```
["1234random9-Dec-2022", "15:16:51", "User66","privateNot", "Scheduled","" ]
```

Expected Output:

```
 [ "1234" // id// ,"random"//file_name//,
"9-Dec-2022"//date//,"15:16:51"//time//,"User66"//username//, "private"//visiblity//, "NotScheduled" // Type of job]
```

Code:

```
describe('Webtable test', () => {
    it('Whole table data', function()  {
        cy
        .get('#query-table tbody tr')
        .should('have.length',10);

        cy.get('#query-table tbody tr:eq(1) td').should('have.length',7);
        cy.get('#query-table tbody tr').each(($el, index, $list) =>{
            cy.wrap($el).find('td').each(($el2, index2, $list2)=>{
               const list=$list2.text().replace(/[\s,]+/g, ' ')
               cy.log("List",list.split(" "))
               const text=list.split(" ")       
               cy.log(text)
            })
        })
    });
})
```

;

Please help me

Comment: You want space between `1234random9-Dec-2022` but not `User66`, what string is consider without space, what are the conditions?. I thought it's numbers but it doesn't seem like it as User66 is no seperated.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast yes

Comment: @AvdhutJoshi ... The OP's _"yes"_ does not clarify anything. Just answer *Buttered_Toast's* question. Do not verify the obvious statement made with the 1st comment. **In addition the question is not precise** since the OP not only wants to add space but also wants to concat what was already separated before ... e.g. `"privateNot", "Scheduled"` becoming `"private", "NotScheduled"`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger,@Buttered_Toast.Apologies I couldn't specify myself well earlier. Actual Result is :["1234random9-Dec-2022", "15:16:51", "User66","privateNot", "Scheduled","" ] and Expecetd result should be :["1234","random","9-Dec-2022","15:16:51","User66", "private", "NotScheduled"]

Comment: @AvdhutJoshi ... _"I have extracted the values out of it and converted it into an array"_ ... One should have a look into how the OP exactly extracts the data. Maybe already there is the source of failure?

Comment: @PeterSeliger ,meaning didn't get you

Comment: @AvdhutJoshi what are other possible values for the 6th `visiblity` table column besides `'private'`?

Comment: @PeterSeliger Public and Shared

Comment: The OP already iterates the `td` collection. Why does the OP then not just programmatically build the array of cell/column values by extracting each from the current td-element ... here `$el2` ... but instead tries to achieve it by what seems to be a splitting and replacing approach of the entire row's text content which of cause will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above comments ...

> @AvdhutJoshi ... *"I have extracted the values out of it and converted it into an array"* ... One should have a look into how the OP exactly extracts the data. Maybe already there is the source of failure?"

> The OP already iterates the `td` collection. Why does the OP then not just programmatically build the array of cell/column values by extracting each from the current td-element ... here `$el2` ... but instead tries to achieve it by what seems to be a splitting and replacing approach of the entire row's text content which of cause will fail.

The next provided example code takes the OP's attempt and changes it according to the suggestions of the second quoted comment. It relies on the validity of `cellItem.text()` for I only could guess from the OP's code whether to extract text content like that.

```
describe('Webtable test', () => {
  it('Whole table data', () => {
    cy
      .get('#query-table tbody tr')
      .should('have.length', 10);
    cy
      .get('#query-table tbody tr:eq(1) td')
      .should('have.length', 7);
    cy
      .get('#query-table tbody tr')
      .each(rowItem => {
        const cellContentList = [];
        cy
          .wrap(rowItem)
          .find('td')
          .each(cellItem =>
            cellContentList.push(
              cellItem.text().trim()
            )
          );
        console.log({ cellContentList });
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: @AvdhutJoshi ... The OP might consider rewarding the remote analysis, the code review and the final fix by [voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) on and/or [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the above answer.